# Keras unexpected keyword argument 'dim_ordering'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am developing in Keras with tensorflow backend. My program runs smoothly on two machine but the third. It gives me the following error message:

```
conv1 = Convolution2D(nb_filter=64,nb_col=7,nb_row=7,subsample=(2,2),border_mode='same', init=my_init,)(input)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 546, in __call__
self.build(input_shapes[0])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 436, in build
constraint=self.W_constraint)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 418, in add_weight
weight = initializer(shape, name=name)
TypeError: my_init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dim_ordering'
```

I updated keras and tensorflow to the most recent version but the error still occurs. Here is the corresponding code segment:

```
def my_init(shape, name=None):
   return kr.initializations.normal(shape, scale=1e-1, name=name)

def build(input_shape, output_shape, use_l2_norm):
   tf.python.control_flow_ops = tf
   input = Input(shape=input_shape)

   conv1 = Convolution2D(nb_filter=64,nb_col=7,nb_row=7,
           subsample=(2,2),border_mode='same', init=my_init)(input)
```

The weird thing is that from the error message it is clear that the line:

```
   weight = initializer(shape, name=name)
```

in keras/engine/topology.py calls the my_init method but there is no parameter dim_ordering which is passed the my_init method

BTW the keras.json is the same on all three machin:

```
{
"image_dim_ordering": "tf", 
"epsilon": 1e-07, 
"floatx": "float32", 
"backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

Comment: let me guess: my_init's parameters shape is not properly defined. Try to set dim_ordering in conv1 explicitly.

Comment: Nope. the problem was that I had a newer version of keras in which it actually passes a dim_ordering to the my_init method. I updated the method like this: my_init(shape, name=None, dim_ordering=None). and it worked. It must be some python magic that in the  initializer(shape, name=name) it doesn't seems it passes this parameter but eventually it does

Comment: And have you seen the typo in your definition? There is a trailing separator at the end of = Convolution2D(nb_filter=64,nb_col=7,nb_row=7,subsample=(2,2),border_mode='same', init=my_init,)

Comment: Try commenting out image_dim_ordering from json file and instead write image_data_format